# Where is it mentioned that tool recommendation questions are off-topic?

Tags: support

[My question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52680/is-there-an-ios-version-of-modern-ie) was put on hold with this reason:

> "Questions asking us to recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Pro Webmasters as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." – John Conde

The box links to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions I don't see such a rule here.

That page links to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic I don't see such a rule here.

That page links to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask I don't see such a rule here.

I'm not whining that my question was put on-hold, but I honestly made sure to look through the various help pages to see if I could ask my question, before I typed it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I propose that we update the text of https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic to this:

Pro Webmasters Stack Exchange is for professional and enthusiast webmasters focused on questions about how to operate websites.  Questions here are commonly about search engine optimization (SEO), domains, and web-hosting.

There are some types of questions about running websites that we don't accept:

- **HTML, JavaScript, or CSS coding** -- Detailed questions about how to code something are usually a better fit for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) where there are more programmers that answer questions.
- **System and network administration** -- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) participants are much more likely to know the technical details on topics such as DNS and Apache configuration than people who answer questions here.
- **Web sites out of your control** -- If the question is about another site (such as Gmail or Facebook) and not about your own website, it is off-topic here. [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.
- **Usage of web browsers and other software** -- [Super User](https://superuser.com/) is available for questions about how to use software in ways that is not directly related to running your own website.
- **Content management systems (CMSs)** -- There are specific Stack Exchange sites for several CMSs.  Use those sites for [WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), [Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/), [Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/),  [Tridion](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/), or [Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/).  Questions about other CMSs may be asked here on Pro Webmasters.
- **Recommendations for sites and resources** -- Questions that ask for recommendation of an external website or resource attract lots of self promotion and spam answers.  In addition, answers to such questions quickly become out of date.  Such questions are closed as off-topic.
- **Specific to only your site** - If the answers to your question could only apply to your site, we won't accept your question.  For example, we would close questions such as "What am I doing wrong here?" or "Please review my site."
- **Topics with a "catch all" question and answer** -- Many topics are covered by a question with a comprehensive answer.  Other questions about the topic are marked as duplicate.  Some examples from [the list of catch-all questions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catch-all) are:

  - [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)
  - [Which Content Management System (CMS)/Wiki should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-wiki-should-i-use)
  - [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

For more help, see [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Please [look around](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search) to see if your question has been asked before. It's also OK to [ask and answer your own question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/self-answer).

If your question is not specifically on-topic for Pro Webmasters Stack Exchange, it may be on topic for [another Stack Exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites). If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may [commit to](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) or [propose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) a new site at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.

Comment: (I can't suggest an edit) The plural of *CMS* would be *[CMSs](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/SOS)* or *CMSes*, and there's one place where you wrote *CMS systems*. +1, thanks for the write-up.

Comment: Thanks, edited.

Comment: Nice one steve for compiling that.

Comment: Since the other moderators have now seen this, I put this text onto the http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic page.

Comment: Consider changing "we won't accept your question" to "probably not a good fit for Pro Webmasters" in "Specific to your site" - This is getting a bit oddly specific, and I realize that's needed to a degree (and partly why we have the page), but we might be able to make it less .. scary :)

Comment: I made that edit on the help page: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic